# How to Resolve DOMException When Decrypting Files with Web Crypto API in a Streaming Manner?

Tags: javascript, encryption, deployment, aes, webcrypto-api

I m trying to encrypt file in browser uisng webcrypto api. I m using chunking mechanism too so that i can encrypt and decrypt large files without crashing browser.

My provided code is working if i m not using chunking mechanism or the file size is less than chunk size ie 1 MB as it wont go to else part  anyway

Please help me with it.

Code for encryption:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Large File Encryption</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input type="file" id="fileInput" >
      <button id="encryptButton">Encrypt</button>
      <a id="downloadLink" style="display: none" download="encrypted-file.txt">Download Encrypted File</a>
      <script>
             // event listener which will listen to encrypt button
         document.getElementById("encryptButton").addEventListener("click", async () => {
             const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
             const file = fileInput.files[0];
             if (!file) {
                 alert("Please select a file.");
                 return;
             }
                
                    
             const chunkSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1 MB chunks
              
             // generating keys 
             const key = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey({ name: "AES-GCM", length: 256 }, true, ["encrypt","decrypt"]);
         
             const keyData = await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey('jwk', key);
         
         // Create a data blob with the key data
         const keyBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(keyData)], { type: 'application/json' });
         
         // Create a download link for the key
         const keyUrl = URL.createObjectURL(keyBlob);
         const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
         downloadLink.href = keyUrl;
         downloadLink.download = 'encryption-key.json';
         downloadLink.click();
         
         const iv=new Uint8Array(12);
    
         
         
         
         
             const reader = new FileReader();
              
              // chunks will be pushed in this array
             const fileData = [];
             let offset = 0;
         
             reader.onload = async function () {
                 const chunk = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
                          
                 // encrypting the chunk using AES-GCM alogorithm
                 const encryptedChunk = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
                     { name: "AES-GCM", iv },
                     key,
                     chunk
                 );
                 
                 // pushing the chunk
                 fileData.push(encryptedChunk);
                 // updating offset
                 offset += chunk.length;
                            
                 // if remaining chunks are left to be read and encrypted           
                 if (offset < file.size) {
                     // calling readslice function to start reading remaining chunks
                     readSlice(offset);
                 } else {
                     // All chunks are encrypted; combine them and provide a download link.
                     const encryptedData = new Blob(fileData, { type: file.type });
                     const url = URL.createObjectURL(encryptedData);
                     const downloadLink = document.getElementById("downloadLink");
                     downloadLink.href = url;
                     downloadLink.style.display = "block";
                     console.log('finished')
                 }
             };
                    
             function readSlice(offset) {
                 // taking part of file
                 const slice = file.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize);
                 // to initiate reading the part of file
                 reader.readAsArrayBuffer(slice);
             }
         
             readSlice(0);
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Code for decryption

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>File Decryption</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>File Decryption</h1>
  
  <!-- Input for the encrypted file -->
  <input type="file" id="encryptedFileInput"  />
  
  <!-- Input for the encryption key (as JSON) -->
  <input type="file" id="keyInput" accept=".json" />
  
  
  
  <button id="decryptButton">Decrypt</button>
  
  <a id="downloadLink" style="display: none;">Download Decrypted File</a>
  
  <script>
    document.getElementById("decryptButton").addEventListener("click", async () => {
      // Get the encrypted file
      const encryptedFileInput = document.getElementById("encryptedFileInput");
      const encryptedFile = encryptedFileInput.files[0];
      
      // Get the encryption key 
      const keyInput = document.getElementById("keyInput");
      
      
      const keyFile = keyInput.files[0];
      
      
      if (!encryptedFile || !keyFile ) {
        alert("Please select the encrypted file and  key.");
        return;
      }
      
      // Read the key and IV as JSON
      const keyData = await keyFile.text();
   
      
      // Convert the JSON data to JavaScript objects
      const keyObj = JSON.parse(keyData);
      

     



const importAlgorithm = {
  name: "AES-GCM"
};


const keyUsage = ["encrypt","decrypt"];
            
     // importing the jwk key 
      const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey("jwk", keyObj, importAlgorithm, false, keyUsage)

      // 1 mb( chunk size while encrypting + 12 bytes(iv size in bytes) ) 
      const chunkSize= (1024*1024)+12
      
      // also tried with
      // const chunkSize= (1024*1024)
      // but no luck


       const reader = new FileReader();
            const fileData = [];
            let offset = 0;

        reader.onload = async function () {
          console.log('chunk loaded')
                const chunk = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
                const decryptedChunk = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
                    { name: "AES-GCM", iv: new Uint8Array(12) },
                    key,
                    chunk
                );
                fileData.push(decryptedChunk);
                offset += chunk.length;

                if (offset < encryptedFile.size) {
                    readSlice(offset);
                } else {
                    // All chunks are decrypted; combine them and provide a download link.
                    const decryptedData = new Blob(fileData, { type: encryptedFile.type });
                    const url = URL.createObjectURL(decryptedData);
                    const downloadLink = document.getElementById("downloadLink");
                    downloadLink.href = url;
                    downloadLink.download="someting.dec"
                    downloadLink.style.display = "block";
                    downloadLink.click()
                    console.log('finished')
                }
            };

            function readSlice(offset) {
                const slice = encryptedFile.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize);
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(slice);
            }

            readSlice(0);









      
    
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For the file above 1MB(aka when chunking mechanism is used) i m getting the following error

> DOMException: The operation failed for an operation-specific reason

I tried to simply decrypt without using chunks but still i m facing error. Maybe there is some issue with encryption part. I expect that just like the code works for file size less than 1 MB which is chunk size, it works too by encrypting and decrypting properly chunk by chunk.

Edit: I changed iv length from 12 bytes to 16 bytes and its now working. But one problem still exist i.e. browser crashing. Anyway to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```js
const chunkSize= (1024*1024)+16 // change in decrypt.html
```

I have arrived at this conclusion by running your code and observing the size difference between encrypted file and decrypted file. So I noticed that there is extra 16 bits(instead of 12) per slice in encrypted file.

Comment: Thanks this cleared it .Before closing the question, I want advice related to this streamline reading. With this I am able to encrypt and decrypt larger file than without using chunking mechanism. Earlier my browser was crashing above 100 mb but now it is crashing above 500 mb. Any way to deal with crashing for such large files?

Comment: Maybe it's device limitation. Bcz for me, it was working even for 1 GB large file.

Comment: i want to upvote your answer but i cant